# String inversion and buffer overrun

Tags: c, visual-studio, buffer-overflow

I created a function to reverse a string.

I know the code for this function is already available on the web but I'm starting to develop in C and I want to do my functions to understand what I'm doing.

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


char* reverseString(char* chaineFonc);
    
    char* reverseString(char* chaineFonc)
    {
        // Initialization
        int stringLength = strlen(chaineFonc);
        char* response = (char*)malloc((stringLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
        int numCarac = stringLength - 1;
    
        // For each Character in the String
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        {
            // Memorization
            response[i] = chaineFonc[numCarac];
    
            // Decrement
            numCarac--;
        }
        // End - For each Character in the String
    
        // Finalization
        response[stringLength] = '\0';
    
        return response;
    }


    int main(int nbArg, char** listeArg)
    {
        printf("\n%s",reverseString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"));
    }
```

This code works but I have an alert under Visual Studio which indicates a buffer overflow when I have this code `response[stringLength] = '\0';`

And I don't understand why.

The Warnings :

**Avertissement C6011** Déréférencement du pointeur NULL 'response'. (Dereferencing NULL pointer 'response')

**Avertissement C6386** Dépassement de la mémoire tampon lors de l'écriture sur 'response'. (Buffer overflow while writing to 'response')

Comment: Where are your `#include`s? They really matter.

Comment: Just what is `int main(int nbArg, char** listeArg, char** listeVarEnv)` and which compiler documentation told you you could write code like that? Don't do really strange things just for the heck of it! Use standard C `int main (int argc, char** argv)`. If you must and your compiler supports it, you could add `char *envp[]` which isn't standard C but a common extension.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't show inclusions but I do. This code works. If I didn't #include I would get errors.

Comment: I think Visual Studio is wrong.  It doesn't look like an overflow to me.  The only issue I see is the guaranteed memory leak because you don't capture return.  But that is sort of out of the scope of the question.  Maybe VS is being a bit paranoid, but I think you are correct.

Comment: @Juan if you show an example put the includes as well. _You_ know that you've put the includes, but _we_ don't know this. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: @Lundin I took over a statement from the "main" on some code where I needed to list Windows environment variables. But you are right I can remove it in this code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  Could they not be inferred?  `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>`

Comment: @Jason maybe, but if the OP put them in his code and he doesn't show them in the question then there is a problem.

Comment: @Juan MSVC like many other older compilers used to go ape if you used malloc without including stdlib.h. As in silently producing incorrect code without warnings, that would crash & burn. This is a well-known, infamous bug that was caused by C90 being a bad version of the C language. So please post a minimal example with all includes since it _does_ matter - you could be using an old version of MSVC for all we know.

Comment: It is better if you could include the compiler details, complete error given by the compiler.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I edit my code and I added the includes

Comment: Your code with the includes looks fine to me. Please let us know the __verbatim__ error message you get from Visual Studio.

Comment: BTW if  omit `#include <stdlib.h` and if I compile the code as x64, I get a crash here: `response[i] = chaineFonc[numCarac];`. But that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky So MSVC is _still_ not C99 compliant. `/std:c99` doesn't help.  It does give a warning "C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'char *' of greater size" but the compiler is _not_ allowed to perform that implicit int conversion. This is such a trash compiler...

Comment: @Jabberwocky My Visual Studio is in french but I have this warnings. **C6011** : pointer name dereference and **C6386** : buffer overflow

Comment: @Juan so you have a warning when you _compile_ your code. Please confirm. And also show the **verbatim** original french warnings along with your english translations in your question and not in comments. [Edit] the question

Comment: @Jabberwocky I edited my question adding the warnings

Comment: Warning C6011 could be because the code does not check the value returned by `malloc()`. (`response` *could* be `NULL`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should have told us you were running the static code analysis which probably gave you these warnings:

```
C:\Users\XXX\main.c(30): warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'response':  the writable size is '((stringLength+1))*sizeof(char)' bytes, but 'stringLength' bytes might be written.
C:\Users\XXX\main.c(30): warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'response'.
```

You get warning C6011 because `response` can potentially be `NULL`, because `malloc` may return a `NULL` pointer, although this is very unlikely to happen, especially as the allocaterd size is very small.

You can get rid of this warning by adding some code:

```
...
char* response = (char*)malloc((stringLength + 1) * sizeof(char));

if (response == NULL)  // <<< add this
  exit(1);             // <<< add this

int numCarac = stringLength - 1;
...
```

Warning C6386 is certainly a bug of the Microsoft static code analyzer, I don't see any problems in this code. Especially as the following  error message is contradictory:

```
`the writable size is '((stringLength+1))*sizeof(char)' bytes,
 but 'stringLength' bytes might be written`
```

Comment: thank's for your time et your answer. Warning C6011 is gone.
And yes I reviewed the malloc code and size.